# Web app to serve images and record number of viewers

Tags: gratis, web-apps, images, web-server

Can anyone recommend a web app that will serve images and provide a report of the number of viewers?

It would be great if the app also provided other statistics in the report, such as the geolocation of the viewers and what web browser they are using.

I just need to serve 1 or 2 small images, each under 100KB.

The service must be free of charge (gratis).

Answer (score 1):

[Imgur](https://imgur.com/) provides this service. It is free. You can upload as much images as you like. Once an image is uploaded, you can visit its statistics. This will provide you with the number of views, source of origin (Facebook, Twitter etc.) and much more.

[This](https://blog.imgur.com/2014/01/27/image-analytics/) is the official blog post of Imgur that details these features.

Note that you will have to sign up to access the statistics even though it is possible to upload images without an account. Also it takes some time for the statistics to be available once the images are uploaded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aswin!  You mentioned that it takes some time for the statistics to be available once the images are uploaded.  Is that a *one time lag* after the images are uploaded, or a delay always present in being able to retrieve updated statistics?  Either way, about how long is the delay?  Thanks again.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard its a one time lag. You should be able to access the statistics within 1 hour. The view count is not lost.. :)

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Happy to help. :)